# How I can convert a special select from sql statement into criteria API

Tags: java, jakarta-ee, select, criteria-api

Today I have a problem with my existing sql statement. I want need to use it with TomEE (Tomcat+Java EE) and written in criteria down.

I have these selects in my sql:

```
SELECT
 dest.zc_zip as zip,
 dest.zc_location_name as locname,
 ACOS(
        SIN(RADIANS(src.zc_lat)) * SIN(RADIANS(dest.zc_lat)) 
        + COS(RADIANS(src.zc_lat)) * COS(RADIANS(dest.zc_lat))
        * COS(RADIANS(src.zc_lon) - RADIANS(dest.zc_lon))
    ) * 6371 as distance
```

What i did?
For the first 2 select was it no problem, but the last one, i don't know how i can realize it:

```
@PersistenceUnit(unitName="umkreissuche-jpa")
private EntityManagerFactory emf = null;
private EntityManager em = null;
..
em = emf.createEntityManager();
// getting criteria builder
CriteriaBuilder cb = em.getCriteriaBuilder();
// setting ZCCoordinate model as main profile
CriteriaQuery<ZCCoordinate> cq = cb.createQuery(ZCCoordinate.class);
// setting from
Root<ZCCoordinate> dest = cq.from(ZCCoordinate.class);
// setting inner join
Join<ZCCoordinate, ZCCoordinate> src = dest.join("zcId", JoinType.INNER);
// setting selects
cq.multiselect(dest.get("zcZip").alias("zip"), dest.get("zcLocationName").alias("locname"), ???);
```

Here is my ZCCoordinate model:

```
package de.circlesearch.model;

import java.io.Serializable;

import javax.persistence.*;


/**
 * The persistent class for the zc_coordinates database table.
 * 
 */
@Entity
@Table(name="zc_coordinates")
@NamedQuery(name="ZCCoordinate.findAll", query="SELECT z FROM ZCCoordinate z")
public class ZCCoordinate implements Serializable {
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy=GenerationType.AUTO)
    @Column(name="zc_id", unique=true, nullable=false)
    private int zcId;

    @Column(name="zc_lat", nullable=false)
    private double zcLat;

    @Column(name="zc_loc_id", nullable=false)
    private int zcLocId;

    @Column(name="zc_location_name", nullable=false, length=255)
    private String zcLocationName;

    @Column(name="zc_lon", nullable=false)
    private double zcLon;

    @Column(name="zc_zip", nullable=false, length=10)
    private String zcZip;

    public ZCCoordinate() {
    }

    public int getZcId() {
        return this.zcId;
    }

    public void setZcId(int zcId) {
        this.zcId = zcId;
    }

    public double getZcLat() {
        return this.zcLat;
    }

    public void setZcLat(double zcLat) {
        this.zcLat = zcLat;
    }

    public int getZcLocId() {
        return this.zcLocId;
    }

    public void setZcLocId(int zcLocId) {
        this.zcLocId = zcLocId;
    }

    public String getZcLocationName() {
        return this.zcLocationName;
    }

    public void setZcLocationName(String zcLocationName) {
        this.zcLocationName = zcLocationName;
    }

    public double getZcLon() {
        return this.zcLon;
    }

    public void setZcLon(double zcLon) {
        this.zcLon = zcLon;
    }

    public String getZcZip() {
        return this.zcZip;
    }

    public void setZcZip(String zcZip) {
        this.zcZip = zcZip;
    }

    @Override
    public int hashCode() {
        final int prime = 31;
        int result = 1;
        result = prime * result + zcId;
        return result;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean equals(Object obj) {
        if (this == obj) {
            return true;
        }
        if (obj == null) {
            return false;
        }
        if (!(obj instanceof ZCCoordinate)) {
            return false;
        }
        ZCCoordinate other = (ZCCoordinate) obj;
        if (zcId != other.zcId) {
            return false;
        }
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return "ZCCoordinate [zcId=" + zcId + ", zcLat=" + zcLat + ", zcLocId="
                + zcLocId + ", zcLocationName=" + zcLocationName + ", zcLon="
                + zcLon + ", zcZip=" + zcZip + "]";
    }

}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This Problem cant be solved on my side. It gives to much problems to convert the trigonometric functions on select path. Native SQL Statement doesn't help to, because JPQL doesn't support trigonometric functions too.

I use JDBC driver and execute the sql statement directly.

Answer (score 0):

My solution would be create a transient field named distance with the calculation need to obtain that value, this will work as you are not querying by distance if you will that is not going to work.

```
@Transient private double distance;


public double getDistance(){ ACOS(
        SIN(RADIANS(src.zc_lat)) * SIN(RADIANS(dest.zc_lat)) 
        + COS(RADIANS(src.zc_lat)) * COS(RADIANS(dest.zc_lat))
        * COS(RADIANS(src.zc_lon) - RADIANS(dest.zc_lon))
    ) * 6371 as distance }
```

Just consider if you are not using distance value within a where condition.

Comment: No, i dont need the distance field for any querying, only for the order by part at the end. I tell u if that works.

Comment: [@Koitoer](http://stackoverflow.com/u/1869933/)I tried to do that, but my IDE tells me "The method toRadians(double) in the type Math is not applicable for the arguments (Path<Object>)".
Double part1 = Math.acos(Math.sin(Math.toRadians(src.get(""))));

Comment: I take this in my model code:
 @Transient private double distance;
 public double getDistance(Join<ZCCoordinate,ZCCoordinate> join, Root<ZCCoordinate> root){
  Double part1 = Math.sin(Math.toRadians(join.get("zcLat")) * Math.sin(Math.toRadians(root.get("zcLat"))));
  Double part2 = Math.cos(Math.toRadians(join.get("zcLat")) * Math.cos(Math.toRadians(root.get("zcLat"))));
  Double part3 = Math.cos(Math.toRadians(join.get("zcLon")) - Math.toRadians(root.get("zcLon")));
  distance = Math.acos(part1 + part2 * part3) * 6371;
  return (double) Math.round(distance * 100) / 100;
 }
Err:Path not Double